# How to fix Wifi Limited connection issues in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wifi-configuration

I have Wifi Limited connection issue in Windows 8. Which is on my Samsung laptop. This issue occur only while I boot the machine not in the middle of usage. Is it samsung issue or windows issue? Same time my mobile phone can connect with the wifi without any issue.

I use to disconnect and connect multiple time to get access. But this can't be a solution every time. Can any one suggest a working solution.

More detail:

I further investigate on this issue. I have Ubuntu and Windows 8 on this machine. The issue only on windows 8.

Comment: When you are connected, what is the strength of the signal? Does it occur when your laptop is closer to the access point? How many other devices are on the network?

Comment: It is power full wifi zone. And on same table.

Comment: Can you confirm that your IP configuration is set to automatic in Windows 8?

Comment: Windows 8 was lacking many options when it came out, improved by 8.1 and then by 10. Why don't you upgrade? It's free.

Comment: A common problem with wireless drivers on Windows. What wireless card are you using and what driver(s)?

Comment: what model is your PC? this can be found on the bottom of your laptop, or in the battery compartment  (remove the battery)

Comment: First thing to check would be looking for up-to-date drivers of your WiFi card. Did you search for those?

Answer (score 1):

Could possibly be a driver problem, upgrade to the latest driver for your OS and see what happens. Otherwise check the laptop or wifi adapters vendor website for known issues with your OS.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be cause due to not being able to use WPA2(AES) encryption of your router. I had this problem when I was using windows 8.1. One way was I solve this problem is upgrading the os to windows 10 (since it's free) but in windows 10 also I have to upgrade two times. Other way I used to solve this problem is lower the encryption from WPA2 to WPA. To do this you have to connect router using ethernet cable and type 192.168.1.1 in web browser and give username **admin** and default password is also **admin**. Then find out WLAN section the security sub section. then set encryption to WPA. You may need have to provide the wifi password again(pre-shared key). (In my router WLAN is under **setup** but it may change according to the router you use, but not a problem to find it)  FYI lowering security may cause you side effects